# Laravel Multiple One To One Relationship In User Model

Tags: php, database, laravel, model

im trying to create a one to one relationship with the table user,student and teacher. The problem is, when i run LARAVEL TINKER, app\user::find('a123')->teacher it displays the b345 data and doesnt display NULL. New in Laravel. Thanks

Below is the table with their PK.

**User table**

```
user_id | type
a123    |  1
b345    |  2
```

**Student table**

```
student_id| name
a123      |  Danny
```

**Teacher table**

```
teacher_id| name
b345      |  Mr.Mark
```

and this BELOW is the models.

**User Model**

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
public function student(){

    return $this->hasOne(student::class,'student_id');
}
public function teacher(){

    return $this->hasOne(teacher::class,'teacher_id');
}
```

**Student Model** (Teacher model is just the same with teacher_id as PK)

```
protected $primaryKey = 'student_id';


public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From you description, student should belongs to user, also teach

In User Model

```
public function student(){

    return $this->hasMany(Student::class,'student_id');
}
```

In Student Model

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'student_id');
}
```

Comment: actually there are 2 types of users. 1 is student n 1 is teacher. The user table contains only user id n password and the other data such as the name and age can be found on student and teacher table. so its a 1to1 relationship as 1 user holds only 1 user data(student/teacher)